# Google-o-meter custom range

Tags: charts

One is supposed to be able to create a custom range for a Google-O-Meter gauge, but I cannot figure out the syntax or find an example.  `chxr=0,0,1500` is the parameter, and in this example I'm trying to set a range of 0 to 1500.

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=gom&chd=t:1000&chs=200&chls=2|0&chco=ff0000,ffff00,00ff00&chf=bg,s,00000000&chxt=y&chxr=0,0,1500

The documentation on the range states that you have to use chxt to display an axis in order to use chxr to set a custom range, but I just can't get 'er done!  I can see the range labels change to indicate it is 0-1500, but the meter doesn't reflect the T:1000 value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK--got it:

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=gom&chd=t:1250&chs=400&chls=2|0&chco=ff0000,ffff00,00ff00&chf=bg,s,00000000&chxt=y&chds=0,1500&chxr=0,0,1500,250

The chds parameter is the one that controls the scaling.  The chxr parameter just changes the range labels, not the actual range.